# Find $f(x, y)$ when $f(2x + 1, 3y -1) = 4x^2 + 9y^2 + 4x - 6y + 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find $f(x, y)$ when $f(2x + 1, 3y -1) = 4x^2 + 9y^2 + 4x - 6y + 2$

I don't understand, how can we pass two things to a function? Can somebody explain what is this function, please?

Comment: Let $u=2x+1$ and $v=3y-1$, then try to rewrite $4x^2 + 9y^2 + 4x - 6y + 2$ using only $u$ and $v$.

Comment: two linear change of variables $u = 2x + 1, v = 3y-1$ and their inverses.

Comment: You can also just see immediately that $4x^2 + 9y^2 + 4x - 6y + 2 = (2x+1)^2 + (3y-1)^2$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is a function of two variables. Even though it is written as f(x, y) understand that these $x$ and  $y$ variables are local to the function definition. ie: they are different to the $x$ and $y$ used in the second expression.

To avoid confusion it would be better to use different variable names.

Example:

$f(t, u)$

where

$t = 2x + 1$

and

$u = 3y - 1$

so $f(t,u) = 4x^2 + 9y^2 + 4x - 6y + 2$

the first step to solving this problem is to replace the $x$ and $y$ with $u$ and $t$

ie:

$f(t,u) = 4x^2 + 9y^2 - 6y + (2x 1) + (2x + 1) $

$f(t,u) = 4x^2 + 9y^2 - 6y + t + t $

thats the first step, see if you can get the rest

Comment: Also notice that x = (t - 1) / 2
and y = (u + 1)/3

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $t = 2x+1, u = 3y-1 \Rightarrow x = \dfrac{t-1}{2}, y = \dfrac{u+1}{3}$, then substitute $x, y$ into the right side to get the formula.